# How to get the sum Percentage of duplicate field name

Tags: sql-server

In my OrderDetails table getting the percentage Amount for each row works fine. I want the duplicate Product name row to combine its percentage as one. I have tried two difference ways but don't know how to apply Group or any other suitable method to accomplish thisl Kindly assist

| ID | Product | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana | 2.00 |
| 2 | Pawpaw | 4.00 |
| 3 | Banana | 2.00 |

**this**

```
select Product, Amount,
       (Amount * 100 / sum(Amount) over ()) as Percentage
from OrderDetails
```

**And this**

```
SELECT Product, Amount / (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM OrderDetails ) *100 AS AmountPercentage 
FROM OrderDetails
```

Output from the codes above

| ID | Product | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana | 25 |
| 2 | Pawpaw | 50 |
| 3 | Banana | 25 |

My expected output sgould be

| ID | Product | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana | 50 |
| 2 | Pawpaw | 50 |

Comment: use "group by" to bunch the bananas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use window function

```
select  Id,Product,perAmount from (
select id, Product ,round( 100.0* sum(Amount) over (partition by Product) / sum(Amount) over () ,2) as perAmount
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Product order by id) as rw

from Orderss
)a
where rw=1
```

with Group by

```
select min(id) as id, Product ,round( 100.0* sum(Amount) / max( Sumall) ,2) as perAmount
from Orderss
inner join (select sum(Amount) Sumall from Orderss) a on 1=1
group by Product
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/GFpxre2y)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `GROUP BY Product` first. Then you do a window function over the aggregation ie `SUM(SUM(..)) OVER ()`

```sql
SELECT
  MIN(od.ID) AS ID,
  od.Product,
  SUM(od.Amount) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(od.Amount)) OVER () AS Amount
FROM OrderDetails od
GROUP BY
  od.Product;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/RtAHgIsm)

It's unclear what you want for `ID` but I've gone for `MIN(ID)`